# IllegalArgumentException - did not match expected type unable to build the query

Tags: java

I am trying to write the below JPQL query .

```
List<Person> personList = query
            .from(person)
            .innerJoin(person.address, address)
            .where(address.status.eq("active")
            .fetch();
```

Below is the exception thrown after executing the above lines:

```
nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [select person
from Person person
  inner join person.address as address
where address.status = ?1] did not match expected type [com.org.myProject.entity.Address (n/a)]
```

Comment: What is `person.address`?

Comment: @MattU - Please see the entity classes added above. I want to fetch the list of person whose address with status is "active". I have build the same in JPQL query shown above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can u try this

```
EntityManager em = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT DISTINCT p FROM Person p INNER JOIN p.address a");
List<Person> resultList = query.getResultList();
```